# Reduced Graphics Mode, No Wireless, No Bluetooth at boot, 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, boot, wireless, bluetooth, lts

I've read many posts here and elsewhere on the topics mentioned in the Subject.  I've tried many of the proposed 'fixes' but, quite frankly, I couldn't repeat back to you what all I have tried.

This all seems to originate with an update that came through a couple of months ago.  No, I don't know exactly which one.

Nearly every boot, multiple times per day, the events occur in this order.
- Boot bring me to a black screen with a dialog box indicating that I will be in reduced graphics mode.  I click OK.
- Another dialog appears.  There are a number of options there, troubleshooting is one of them.  Again, click OK using the default.
- After maybe 15-20 seconds, I get the normal login screen.
- Once logged in I get several dialog boxes asking me if I want to report the problem.  I've reported each one since this first started occurring. 
- Before I got the hang of restarting the wireless network, the reporting would fail due to lack of connectivity.
- If I don't restart the wireless by hand, I won't have any wireless connection.
- The Bluetooth will not restart.  I've tried stop, start and restart all without any results.

I'm happy to post any logs you need in order to help resolve this, I will just need the command line information.

The laptop is HP Probook 6570b.  4GB RAM.

Wireless Info: Broadcom BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n

Dual boot with Windoze 10 on the other side.  Windoze has no issues that I am aware of but I don't use it much.

Ubuntu is 4.13.0-43-generic #48~16.04.1-Ubuntu
x86 64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I know there are probably a ton of details missing here, so feel free to ask, I'll share whatever you need to help me figure out what is causing this craziness.

Thanks in advance for taking time to read and offer suggestions.